# PHP date - get beginning and ending day of given week from format W-m-Y

Tags: php, date

I have an array of dates in format `W-m-Y`.

From e.g. `34-08-2016` I would like to get something like `20-08-2016 - 26-08-2016`. Those days from requested format, aren't real.

Any idea how to tackle it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this

```
function getStartAndEndDate($week, $year) {
  $dto = new DateTime();
  $dto->setISODate($year, $week);
  $ret['week_start'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  $dto->modify('+6 days');
  $ret['week_end'] = $dto->format('Y-m-d');
  return $ret;
}

$week_array = getStartAndEndDate(34,2016);

echo "start date ".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($week_array['week_start'])).'<br>';
echo "End date ".date('d-m-Y',strtotime($week_array['week_end']));
```

Comment: Props for using `DateTime`, which is a much cleaner way to do this

Comment: Thank you for help. This is the cleanest and IMO the best solution. Approved ;)

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
function getWeekDates($year, $week)
{
    $from = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-1")); //Returns the date of monday in week
    $to = date("Y-m-d", strtotime("{$year}-W{$week}-7"));   //Returns the date of sunday in week     
    return  $from ." - ". $to;        
    //return "Week {$week} in {$year} is from {$from} to {$to}.";
}
$year = 2016;   
$week = '34';
echo getWeekDates($year, $week);
```

**[DEMO](https://eval.in/664319)**

Comment: Thanks for help, but try to pass those vars: `$year = 2017; 
$week = 1;`. In that case, your solution will fail.

Comment: @kkochanski : if you pass data in single quotes it will work fine : https://eval.in/664319

Answer (score 1):

Try this, hope this helps.., also you can optimize it..

```
$date = "34-08-2016";
list($week_no, $month, $year) = explode("-", $date);
$date_obj = new DateTime();
$date_obj->setISODate($year,$week_no);
$day = $date_obj->format('w');
$week_start = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('-'.$day.' days', strtotime($date_obj->format('Y-m-d'))));
$week_end = date('m-d-Y', strtotime('+'.(6-$day).' days', strtotime($date_obj->format('Y-m-d'))));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php
$date = '38-10-2016';
$date = explode('-',$date);

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "$date[2]W$date[0]".'monday this week' ) ), "\n";   

echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime( "$date[2]W$date[0]".'sunday this week' ) ), "\n";
```

This will collect the week number of the date you are given, and look for the Monday and Sunday of that week.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this

```
function date_of_week($date)
{
    echo date("d-m-Y",$date)."\n";

    $day_of_week = date('N', $date); # 0->sunday, 1-> monday etc...
    echo "\tday of week:$day_of_week\n";
    #I assume you begin the week on monday.
    $start_week_date = $date - ($day_of_week-1)*3600*24;
    $end_week_date = $start_week_date + 6*3600*24;

    return date('d-m-Y', $start_week_date)." - ".date('d-m-Y', $end_week_date);

}


for($i=16;$i<24;$i++)
{
    echo date_of_week(mktime(0,0,0,10,$i,2016))."\n\n";
}
```

Comment: Type last line, `$end_week_date` also I have it coming out as `06-10-2018 - 12-10-2018` ?

Comment: The same as @Blinkydamo